# How can I force taskbar buttons to ALWAYS be on the same display as their windows in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I've got multiple displays, and I've selected the option for each display to have its own taskbar and for the taskbars to show the buttons only for the windows that are on those displays:

[image: Windows 10 Settings]

For most windows, this works fine, but I'm finding some windows/applications do not do this initially, or in some cases not at all.

For example, Steam. I keep my steam friends list and chat windows on a secondary display.  However, whenever a new steam-related window is opened, such as a chat, the taskbar button will appear on my primary display's taskbar.  I have to move the window onto the primary display and then back over in order to get it to move.

Another example was Treesize Pro.  That program's taskbar button would stubbornly remain on my primary taskbar no matter where the window was or what I did to try and move it.  However, this particular case no longer occurs since I recently updated the program.

At any rate, currently the only way I know how to "fix" all of the taskbar buttons is to reload the taskbar by restarting the explorer shell.  This isn't a very elegant solution, and it has to be done manually.

Is there any better way of forcing the buttons to be on the correct taskbar?

Note:  I've tested DisplayFusion and I do not like it, so I'm not considering that a solution, but I am open to the suggestion of other 3rd party apps that might help.

Thanks!